# Why the requirement of std::ranges::lower_bound differs from std::lower_bound?

Tags: c++, algorithm, range

I noticed the non-ranges version requires that the compare predicate is a BinaryPredicate [[alg.sorting.general.2]](https://eel.is/c++draft/alg.sorting#general-2), but the ranges version requires `std::indirect_strict_weak_order` [[lower.bound]](https://eel.is/c++draft/alg.sorting#lower.bound) (which bans me to use less_equal).

I searched stackoverflow but only found a question about whether there's a difference, also none of the answerer explained why there's a difference. So I open this question hoping to figure this out.

**Edit:**

I happened to find [N1313](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2001/n1313.html) discussed this and [LWG 270](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue270) allowed to invoke `std::lower_bound` with predicate that dosen't satisfy strict_weak_order like `less_equal`. Now the standard says,

> All of the algorithms in [alg.binary.search] are versions of binary search and assume that the sequence being searched is partitioned with respect to an expression formed by binding the search key to an argument of the comparison function. - [[alg.binary.search.general]](https://eel.is/c++draft/alg.binary.search.general)

> Preconditions: The elements e of [first, last) are partitioned with respect to the expression
> bool(invoke(comp, invoke(proj, e), value)). - [[lower.bound]](https://eel.is/c++draft/lower.bound#2)

Answers in the related question dosen't explain why `std::ranges::lower_bound` requires `std::indirect_strict_weak_order` instead of relaxing the requirement a bit. So I'm hoping reopen this question to figure it out.

Comment: Using `less_equal` as a comparator doesn't make sense. Why do you want to use it?

Comment: @interjay I writed a [function](https://godbolt.org/z/bWTj14938) to count the longest increasing (`less`) subsequence in a range, and noticed the change to generalize it in order to count the longest *pred* subsequence in a range (which should apply to `less_equal`). That's where I noticed the different requirements between non-range and range version.

Comment: @interjay Hi, I'm currently reading *Efficient Programming with Components*, and noticed the [LWG270](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue270) already makes using `less_equal` in `lower_bound` available since `std::lower_bound` requires "The elements e of [first, last) are partitioned with respect to the expression e < value or comp(e, value)".